# How can I count how many *pairs of cells* have each element meet a condition?

Tags: formula, libreoffice-calc

In LibreOffice Calc, I have two columns (A, B).

I want to count - without adding extra columns, because this operation must be done a large number of times - how many couples (A`i`,B`i`) meet simultaneously a certain condition on A`i` and another certain condition on B`i`.

It surely involves array functions, but I don't quite understand how they work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function for multiple ranges is [COUNTIFS](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/COUNTIFS_function).  For example, this formula counts all pairs from rows 1 to 11 where both A<sub>i</sub> and B<sub>i</sub> are greater than 50.

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A11,">50",B1:B11,">50")
```

This does not need to be entered as an [array formula](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Array_Functions).